# Server Application Unavailable?

Tags: web

i am a developer and i developed the web application(asp.net). It is working in my local server fine when i take new domain and upload the site in to that domain i am getting this error

hi,

After completion of my project. I placed in online the default page is coming but when i click on any link button it is giving this error can you help me. m3connect.in is url of my site and error is

Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable. Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.

Comment: Maybe this question has a better place on Doctype or Stack Overflow.

Comment: this belongs on Stack Overflow.  it will be migrated there shortly; if you associate your accounts (on the accounts tab on your user profile page) you will regain ownership of the question.

Comment: I had the same error. The solution at http://45notestoself.tumblr.com/post/4045132582/server-application-unavailable-in-iis-6 helped me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried granting the IIS_WPG user read and write access to your deployment directory?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try when you get any kind of error is reading carefully the error message, this one says that "An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server", did you found the error message? The application event log can be found by right clicking the "My Pc" icon on the "Manage" option.

It seems that the main cause for this problem is "two applications with different frameworks running on the same pool".

This is a related question:

[Mixing .NET versions between website and virtual directories and the "server application unavailable" error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626422/mixing-net-versions-between-website-and-virtual-directories-and-the-server-app/4630321#4630321)

I know this is an old question but just in case ...