# Server Application Unavailable

Tags: web-services, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I hosted 2 web service on MS Window Server 2003, Standard Edition, Service Pack 2. One is .NET framework 1.1 and the another is 2.0.

In this server, I could browse 2.0 web service but can't 1.1. I got this error message, "Server Application Unavailable".

I try to browse it from my laptop. I get the same error message again.

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a duplicate of this other question:

[Mixing .NET versions between website and virtual directories and the "server application unavailable" error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626422/mixing-net-versions-between-website-and-virtual-directories-and-the-server-app/4630321#4630321)

But I won't mark it as a duplicate because the question sounds different. There are different causes to this error but as I've been reading the main cause seems to be "two asp.net aplications depending on different frameworks and using the same aplication pool". In the cited question the answer says that you should find the cause of the error on the system event log.

Hope it helps someone!